# How do I include multiple statements in my for loop macro?

Tags: c++, macros

This for loop macro is used frequently in competitive programming:

```
#define REP(i, a, b) \
for (int i = int(a); i <= int(b); i++)
```

Now we use it as follows:

```
REP(i, a, b)
   statement;
```

But what if i want to use multiple statement like this?

```
REP(i, a, b)
   statement1;
   statement2;
```

where both the statements are inside the loop. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why the macro?  Obfuscation, or...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
REP(i, a, b)
{
   statement1;
   statement2;
}
```

If that's really what you want. But keep in mind that it will make your code harder to read for anyone but you. Especially considering the fact that `(i=0; i < n; i++)` is more widespread than `(i=0; i <= n; i++)`. 
If your main goal is to avoid writing this long construction yourself every time, I would take a look a snippets in your favorite code editor.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that I found this standard in majority of competitive programming solutions and just wanted to know how to do it. I use vi.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
   statement1;
   statement2;
}
```

There is ABSOLUTELY no reason for using a macro here - it just hides what the code does, and potentially breaks things (e.g. the values of `a` and `b` are not really fitting in an `int`, but the case makes them "fit".